# How do I limit the touch input?

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch, sprite-kit, particles

I am building a Sprite Kit game where the player shoots a particle whenever the screen is pressed. How can I limit the touch inputs (let's say 2 recognized touch inputs per second) so that the player can't just quickly tap the screen to get unlimited shots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution:
Create a BOOL (I prefer to work with properties myself, so):

`@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL touchEnabled;`

Set it to YES in the scene's init. Then it is fairly simple from thereon:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     if (self.touchEnabled){
         self.touchEnabled = NO;
         [self shootParticle];
         [self performSelector:@selector(enableTouch) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
     }
...

- (void)shootParticle{
   // whatever...
}

- (void)enableTouch{
   self.touchEnabled = YES;
}
```

Comment: Just a quick note, in SpriteKit, avoid 'performSelector' if you can. It won't be part of SK's update loop (use SKAction). If you pause your game, it will fire. Same reason why you don't use NSTimer (or GCD for that matter) with SK.

Answer (score 1):

One of many possibilities:

```
@interface YourSceneName (){
    int _amountBullets; //increase every time you shot and just shoot when _fireStop = NO 
    BOOL _fireStop; // init as NO at start
    BOOL _needStartTime; // init as YES at start
    CFTimeInterval _startTime;
}
@end

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

//set starttime
    if(_needStartTime){
        _startTime = currentTime;
        _needStartTime = NO;
    } 

//timeinterval if 2 seconds, renew everything
    if(currentTime - _startTime > 2){
        _startTime = currentTime;
        _amountBullets = 0
        _fireStop = NO;
    }
//set firestop to yes, method should be executed
    if(_amountBullets = 2){
        _fireStop = YES;
    } 
}
```

I am new in SpriteKit but this should work. I bet there are better possibilities. Also i haven´t test the code. It shell show you the logic of how you could do it, hope I could help.
Here is a great [Tutorial](http://makeapppie.com/2014/04/10/slippyflippy-1-1-how-to-make-a-countdown-timer-in-sprite-kit/) for working with time in SpriteKit.